# OnPropertyChanged does not update the View

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged

I have a ListView which has its itemsource to Elements which is a List of Schranken-Objects. The SchrankePresenter is the DataContext of the page(set in the constructor).

The page is displayed correctly, until a button is clicked. If a button is clicked, the value Name of the button should change and the ListView should have one item more, but nothing happens/updates.

Here is the SchrankenPresenter:

```
 public class SchrankePresenter : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private List<Schranke> _elements;
        public List<Schranke> Elements
        {
            get { return _elements; }
            set
            {
                _elements = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Elements");
            }
        }
        public ICommand ClickCommand { get; set; }
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"on Property changed with {propName}");
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public SchrankePresenter()
    {
        var elements = new List<Schranke>();
        for (var i = 1; i < 15; i++)
            elements.Add(new Schranke() { Name = $"{i}: Schranke" });

        Elements = elements;
        Debug.WriteLine("ctor");
        ClickCommand = new DelegateCommand<Schranke>(ClickAction);
    }

    public void ClickAction(Schranke item)
    {
        VibrationDevice.GetDefault().Vibrate(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(150));

        Debug.WriteLine($"{item?.Name} was clicked");
        item.Name = "was clicked";
        OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        Elements.Add(new Schranke() { Name = "addednew element" });
        OnPropertyChanged("Elements");

    }

}
```

The class Schranke has only one member:  `public string Name { get; set; }`

The view looks like:

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Elements, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="lv_schranken" Grid.Row="1" SelectedItem="{Binding  SelectedItem}">

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Height="80"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Command="{Binding ElementName=lv_schranken, Path=DataContext.ClickCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                            Style="{StaticResource TransparentStyle}">
                        <Grid>
                                .
                                .  (some grid stuff)
                                .

                            <TextBlock Name="schranken_name"
                                       Grid.Row="1"
                                       Grid.Column="1"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       FontWeight="ExtraLight"
                                       FontSize="25"
                                       Foreground="Black"
                                       Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>

            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>
```

PS: if some needs the DelegateCommand - Implementation:

```
 public class DelegateCommand<T> : ICommand
    {
    private Action<T> _clickAction;

    public DelegateCommand(Action<T> clickAction)
    {
        _clickAction = clickAction;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _clickAction((T)parameter);
    }
}
```

Comment: `OnPropertyChanged("Name");` should be called in `Schranke` class, in `Name` setter.

Comment: If you had done any research at all you would know that one does not bind to `List<T>`.

Comment: Isn't it possible to use List<T> for binding purpose?

Comment: It is, but you should should not do it; it's inefficient and essentially a hack.

Comment: So a ObservableCollection<T> would be a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your want to bind to a List of items, you should bind to an `ObservableCollection`:

> Represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when
>   items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

For updating the UI from `Viewmodel` we're required to raised `inotifypropertychanged`;  `observablecollection` provides the `inotifypropertychanged`  implementation by default;  we can refer  `observablecollection` for [MVVm pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36202712/wpf-mvvm-pattern).

If you want to use list for the same then you need to **implement the `inotifypropertychanged` on that particular list**